# How to Bind dynamic values in Xaml using WPF in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created application in WPF with two window. In one window i have used with one text box and submit button. Once submit from first window i hide first window and show second window. I have taken some values using first window text value and need to bind in second window Xaml. Actually that values can bind using foreach in html(mvc) but need to bind Xaml for display in second window. Please give some suggestions.

Comment: [`ItemsControl`](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) is the standard way to bind to a list of objects.  Set `ItemsSource` to your list of objects, and create a `DataTemplate` to control the visual elements for each item.

Comment: No problem in that, data from first window should already be in some view-model. Use that viewmodel in another window. That's it.

Comment: Nice .. Thanks @BradleyUffner ..

Comment: Thanks @Divisadero for your suggestion

Comment: @ArunD No problem, if you need more info on how to do it, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below answer, It will work definitely

**Xaml :**

```
<ItemsControl Name="icTodoList">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="200,50,0,30">
                                    <TextBlock>
                                       <Hyperlink TextDecorations="None" NavigateUri="{Binding UriPath}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myImg}">
                                                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" Height="80"  x:Name="myImg" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="5"/>
                                       </Hyperlink>
                                    </TextBlock>

                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Margin="200,30,0,0">
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="22px" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="white"></TextBlock>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

**C# code for binding Values,**

```
 public class DMScreen3 {
    public List<string> AllFiles { get; set; }
              List<BindingFilesContent> items = new List<BindingFilesContent>();
                    if(AllFiles != null)
                    {
                        foreach(var r in AllFiles)
                        {
                            if ((r.ToLower().Contains(".avi") || r.ToLower().Contains(".mp4")) && fileTypes == "video")
                            {
                                items.Add(new BindingFilesContent() { Title = Path.GetFileName(r), UriPath = r, Source = "/images/videoicon.png" });
                            }
        icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
                  }
        }
}
  public class BindingFilesContent
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string UriPath { get; set; }
    }
```